# How to change the offset based on the result

Tags: php, mysql, phalcon

In MYSQL (where also php is allowed)
assume we have the `items` table 
that consists of `id`, `name`, `status`.

And you want to get the item before the last, the following query would work perfectly

```
SELECT * from `items`
WHERE `name` = 'xxx'
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1 
OFFSET 1;
```

However, if the status of this item is in (4,5,6) then I want to get the one before it.
Briefly, it's all about incrementing the offset, but how to do so in the query?

Comment: Some sample code/data and the desired output would be more than helpful for the entire society.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * from `items`
WHERE `name` = 'xxx'
AND status NOT IN ('.implode(',',$the_Array.')
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

the answer was to get rid of the offset